# Do you say there is a few people or there are a few people?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, quantifiers, quantificational-nouns

Which one is correct: "There is a few people" because of the A determiner which is singular, or "there are a few people" because of the noun PEOPLE which is plural?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

'a few' of anything is a small number. It is greater than one, and thus refers to a plural quantity, thus 'are' is the correct verb form.

> few PRONOUN, DETERMINER, & ADJECTIVE
>
> 1a few
>
> A small number of.
>
> as determiner ‘may I ask a few questions?’
>
> as pronoun ‘I will recount a few of the stories told me’
>   ‘there are hundreds of applicants but only a few are selected’

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/few)